# How to write out a MOV video into a raw, uncompressed format?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video in a MOV file format, shot using an IPhone. I have to convert it into an uncompressed raw format, with multiple frames laid out one after the other. This has to be written to a file for post processing.

Is there a stock format out there that I can convert this video to, using ffmpeg? If not, I will have to write a C program to open the MOV file and write out the video. I have never worked in video land before, so I am confused about the options.

I took a look at ffmpeg documentation, and did a web search, but all of them are talking about using ffmpeg as a command line tool, and not about how to write out a file format that I want.

Answer (score 3):

ffmpeg -i file.mov -vcodec rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -f rawvideo file.yuv